# Blue screen after Windows 8.1 update

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, bsod

I have a problem where every few days Windows 8.1 tries to update and it starts the update, gets to 30% and then restarts as normal. However after restart I get a blue screen of death, and the computer then goes into a reboot/blue screen loop. There was no power cut or any interruption during the update.

After a few loops I get the option to repair startup, restore etc. but none of the options fix the issue apart from starting in safe mode. Starting in safe mode then leads to the screen saying 'Unable to complete updates, removing files' or something similar. After two more restarts with this message I am back to a working computer, until the next time...

I have now turned off automatic updates, but is there any way I can find out which particular update is causing the problem? At the moment I have 7 important updates:

- Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3093983)
- Security Update for Internet Explorer Flash Player for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3105216)
- Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3042058)
- Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3080446)
- Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3088195)
- Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3097966)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3083711)

I also have 21 optional updates that I won't list as they weren't trying to be installed. I'm not sure what other information I can provide to help so feel free to let me know.

I still have a working computer so this is not critical, just frustrating and time consuming.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

BlueScreenView says:

> 102215-44578-01.dmp   22/10/2015
>   19:09:48  SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED 0x1000007e  ffffffff`c0000005   fffff802`d370b732   ffffd001`6dd53218   ffffd001`6dd52a20   LubFsFlt.sys    LubFsFlt.sys+78e0                   x64 ntoskrnl.exe+89732                  C:\windows\Minidump\102215-44578-01.dmp 2   15  9600    284,944 22/10/2015
>   19:12:10

Device Manager shots as requested:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: blueScreeView can provide you information on the crash so you can provide it to us.  Specific error messages also help.

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: I was not familiar with BlueScreenView - I will download it now and update the question ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: "but is there any way I can find out which particular update is causing the problem?" Install them one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: While that would be a logical step I was hoping there would be less time-consuming/trial-and-error method. Thanks though!

Comment: LubFsFlt.sys = NDAS LFS Filter from XIMETA. update it

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you but what you just said means absolutely nothing to me! While I'm pretty tech-savvy as a web developer I'm not experienced in the technical side sorry.

Comment: this seems to be a NAS driver. do you use a NAS?

Comment: @magicandre1981 No, not as far as I am aware (if you're referring to network storage then definitely not)

Comment: post a picture of the device manager which shows all devices.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I can't fit one on screen with everything expanded, is collapsed ok or do you want me to look for something specific? Thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you experience this crash of you fail to load that driver?

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't tried to load any drivers... I'm happy to try though if it will help and if you tell me how. Sorry for being an idiot when it comes to this.

Comment: I suggested not loading the driver; Autoruns will accomplish that

Comment: post several pictures of device manager to show all devices

Comment: the LubFsFlt.sys is also used by Lenovo. Go to the lenovo page and get the latest drivers for your device

Comment: have you installed the latest drivers from Lenovo? Does it fix it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry for the slow reply - I downloaded System Update 5 from here: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/tvsu-update and it says 'No packages applicable to your system were found'.

Comment: which lenovo device do you use?

Comment: Lenovo B50-30 - the label on the bottom says this and underneath also 'Model Name: 80ES'

Comment: update all drivers from here: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-b-series-laptops/lenovo-b50-30-notebook#

Comment: I downloaded Service Bridge from that page (after detecting my serial number) and it says I am out of warranty (which is correct). I also tried clicking 'Update your system' further down the page and it says 'Your system is not supported for System Update.'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too today

Solution: Disable Secure Boot from BIOS

Comment: @Ramhound, Ok well as long as this method works, it's still technically the right answer. Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3ptrt9/update_windows_10_insider_preview_october_update/

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I was on mobile this morning. I though I did, guess it didn't save. But it's all fixed now.

Comment: That link relates to a different update (I have no Windows 10 updates or previews) and the dump file error is different. But I'll give it a go as I'm guessing it's a generic fix? Will this prevent the update happening or make it install correctly without the issues? Sorry if it's a stupid question, been a long day...